# Como transformar uma lista em set no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer a intersecção da lista jogador com a lista computador, mas estou recebendo um erro que diz assim: "line 13, in 
print(set(jogador).intersection(computador))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

Alguém saberia dizer onde estou errando?

```
from random import sample

lista = []
for numero in range(1,4):
    jogador = int(input(f'{numero}º número: '))
    lista.insert(numero, jogador)
print(lista)

jogo = list(range(1, 21))
computador = sample(jogo, 3)
print(computador)

print(set(jogador).intersection(computador))
```

Comment: As duas variáveis serão apenas um valor inteiro e não um conjunto, então não tem como calcular a intersecção entre eles. O que exatamente você precisa fazer? Você não faz nada com a variável `lista`?

Comment: Como ambas receberão 3 valores eu achei que isso seria um conjunto. Eu queria saber a intersecção dos 3 valores dados pelo usuário com os 3 valores que o computador vai escolher. Eu usei a lista para criar a lista da variável jogador.

Comment: Tem certeza que deveria ser `set(jogador)` e não `set(lista)`?

Comment: Nossa, era isso mesmo, muito obrigada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perceba que você fez:

```
print(set(jogador).intersection(computador))
```

Mas `jogador` será do tipo inteiro, pois:

```
jogador = int(input(f'{numero}º número: '))
```

Um inteiro não é iterável e, portanto, não pode ser *convertido* para um conjunto fazendo `set(jogador)`, tal como a mensagem de erro informou. Dado que você armazena os valores lidos em `jogador` na lista `lista`, acredito que o correto seria:

```
print(set(lista).intersection(computador))
```

Answer (score 1):

Nem sempre é possível converter o conteúdo de uma `list` para um `set` devido a diferente natureza de cada um desses tipos, veja só:

```
lst = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
s = set( lst )
print( s )
```

Saída:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Repare que o `set` suporta apenas valores únicos, equanto a `list` suporta qualquer conjunto de valores.